# In a Kubernetes deployment yaml, why do we have to match the template labels to the deployment labels in the selector?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes, so this might be obvious, but in a deployment yaml, why do we have to define the labels in the deployment metadata, then define the same labels in the template metadata, but match those separately in the selector?

Shouldn't it be obvious that the template belongs to the deployment it's under?
Is there a use case for a deployment to have a template it doesn't match?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-backend
    spec:
      #...etc
```

I might be missing some key understanding of k8s or yamls.

Having the template with no label, and it seems to work, but I don't understand why. Kubernetes could be auto-magically inserting the labels.

Answer (score 5):

Let's simplify labels, selectors and template labels first.

- The Labels in the metadata section are assigned to the deployment itself.
- The Labels in the `.spec.template` section are assigned to the pods created by the deployment. These are actually called PodTemplate labels.
- The selectors provide uniqueness to your resource. It is used to identify the resources that match the labels in `.spec.selector.matchLabels` section.

Now, it is not mandatory to have all the podTemplate Labels in the matchLabels section. a pod can have many labels but only one of the matchLabels is enough to identify the pods. Here's an use case to understand why it has to be used

"Let’s say you have deployment X which creates two pods with label `nginx-pods` and image `nginx` and another deployment Y which applies to the pods with the same label `nginx-pods` but uses images `nginx:alpine`. If deployment X is running and you run deployment Y after, it will not create new pods, but instead, it will replace the existing pods with `nginx:alpine` image. Both deployment will identify the pods as the labels in the pods matches the labels in both of the deployments `.spec.selector.matchLabels`"

Comment: So what you are saying is that `matchLabels` can be used to target pods from another deployment or replica set. OK, but is it a required field if we just want to match the same ones being defined in the current deployment? And what if they don't match, will the pods not get deployed?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the parameter `matchLabels` decides on which Pods belongs to the given Deployment (and the underlying ReplicaSet). In practice, I have never seen a Deployment with different `labels` than `matchLabels`. So, the reason might be the uniformity between other Kubernetes resources (like Service where the `matchLabels` makes more sense).

I recommend reading the blog post [matchLabels, labels, and selectors explained in detail, for beginners](https://medium.com/@zwhitchcox/matchlabels-labels-and-selectors-explained-in-detail-for-beginners-d421bdd05362).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason for this is actually a lot more complicated than it seems.

In summary, not explicitly defining the `spec.selector.matchLabels` and instead automatically grabbing it from the `spec.template.metadata.labels` caused bugs and inconsistencies if people then decided to define it or update it. As a way to avoid such issues, the field was made explicitly required and immutable.

As for sources, you can find a great [blog post](https://rpadovani.com/kubernetes-deployments) on this issue and one [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50808) of the many linked to this decision.

Answer (score -1):

Because the *Deployment.metadata.labels* belongs to the Deployment resource, and the *Deployment.spec.template.metadata.labels* to the Pods which are handled by the Deployment controller. The Deployment controller knows which Pods are belongs to which Deployment based on the labels on the Pod resources.

This is why you have to specify the labels this way.